# There is any avaliability status for databases in MySQL or MariaDB?

Tags: mysql

i'm currently new at db and it infrastructure and at work i've been trying to monitor a few databases using Zabbix. SQL Server and Oracle DB have some avaliability options about current databases, some kind of online/offline status, but after some looking i couldn't find anything at MySQL documentation that describes the same info that i'm looking for. Does anyone more experienced about MySQL can tell me if that info is avaliable?

Comment: Perhaps if you show what you consider the availability status for Oracle and SQL Server, someone might suggest an alternative in MySQL.

Comment: It's a online/offline status that the default zabbix template for these DBRM offers! For example, in SQL Server is divided in 8 categories, which means:
[0] ONLINE
[1] RESTORING
[2]  RECOVERING | SQL Server 2008 and later
[3] RECOVERY_PENDING | SQL Server 2008 and later
[4] SUSPECT
[5] EMERGENCY | SQL Server 2008 and later
[6] OFFLINE | SQL Server 2008 and later
[7]  COPYING | Azure SQL Database Active Geo-Replication
[11] OFFLINE_SECONDARY | Azure SQL Database Active Geo-Replication

.I'm trying to look for an equivalent status, or some info that can be related to those

Comment: well then, you'll need to look at how Zabbix implements those templates

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the Zabbix Documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/guides/monitor_mysql), you could connect to MySQL and have it start monitoring right away

> Create MySQL user
>
> To monitor a MySQL server, Zabbix requires access to it and its processes. Your MySQL installation already has a user with the required level of access (the user "zabbix" that was created when installing Zabbix), however, this user has more privileges than necessary for simple monitoring (privileges to DROP databases, DELETE entries from tables, etc.). Therefore, a MySQL user for the purpose of only monitoring the MySQL server needs to be created.

> Connect to the MySQL client, create a "zbx_monitor" user (replace  for the "zbx_monitor" user with a password of your choice), and GRANT the necessary privileges to the user:

> ```
> mysql -u root -p
> # Enter password:
> mysql> CREATE USER 'zbx_monitor'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
> mysql> GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT,PROCESS,SHOW DATABASES,SHOW VIEW ON *.* TO 'zbx_monitor'@'%';
> mysql> quit;
> ```

> Once the user is created, you can move on to the next step.

The [Zabbix Documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/guides/monitor_mysql) has so many options for monitoring

One of the simplest queries you can run, would be `SELECT 1 MySQLIsUp;`

If you want to connect and echo the running time, you could run anb elaborate query like this:

### MySQL 5.7+, 8.0+

```
SELECT
    NOW() right_now,sec_a Uptime,
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL sec_a SECOND,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S') mysqld_running_since,
    TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(
        IF(dy=0,'',IF(dy=1,'1 day ',CONCAT(dy,' days '))),
        IF(hr=0,'',IF(hr=1,'1 hr ', CONCAT(hr,' hrs  '))),
        IF(mn=0,'',IF(mn=1,'1 min ',CONCAT(mn,' mins '))),
        IF(sc=0,'',IF(sc=1,'1 sec ',CONCAT(sc,' secs ')))),'  ',' '))
    mysqld_running_time
FROM (SELECT sec_a,dy,hr,mn,MOD(sec_aaaa,60) sc
FROM (SELECT sec_a,dy,hr,FLOOR((sec_aaa - dy*86400 - hr*3600)/60) mn,sec_aaa sec_aaaa
FROM (SELECT sec_a,dy,FLOOR((sec_aa - (dy*86400))/3600) hr,sec_aa sec_aaa
FROM (SELECT sec_a,FLOOR(sec_a/86400) dy,sec_a sec_aa
FROM (SELECT variable_value sec_a FROM performance_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name='Uptime') A) AA) AAA) AAAA) B;
```

### MySQL 5.6, MariaDB

```
SELECT
    NOW() right_now,sec_a Uptime,
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL sec_a SECOND,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S') mysqld_running_since,
    TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(
        IF(dy=0,'',IF(dy=1,'1 day ',CONCAT(dy,' days '))),
        IF(hr=0,'',IF(hr=1,'1 hr ', CONCAT(hr,' hrs  '))),
        IF(mn=0,'',IF(mn=1,'1 min ',CONCAT(mn,' mins '))),
        IF(sc=0,'',IF(sc=1,'1 sec ',CONCAT(sc,' secs ')))),'  ',' '))
    mysqld_running_time
FROM (SELECT sec_a,dy,hr,mn,MOD(sec_aaaa,60) sc
FROM (SELECT sec_a,dy,hr,FLOOR((sec_aaa - dy*86400 - hr*3600)/60) mn,sec_aaa sec_aaaa
FROM (SELECT sec_a,dy,FLOOR((sec_aa - (dy*86400))/3600) hr,sec_aa sec_aaa
FROM (SELECT sec_a,FLOOR(sec_a/86400) dy,sec_a sec_aa
FROM (SELECT variable_value sec_a FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name='Uptime') A) AA) AAA) AAAA) B;
```